# Cannot use morse: Could not initialize audio

Tags: audio, alsa

I am unable to use the `morse` utility, both in GUI and non-GUI terminal:

```
# echo word | morse
Could not initialize audio: Connection refused
Can't access speaker.
```

**Why do I have this error and how to use `morse` with alsamixer?**

From `/usr/share/doc/morse/README`:

```
Currently supported devices:
 X11:    The X11 window system. (Warning: not all X11 implementations handle
         duration and frequency of beeps properly!)
 Linux:  The IBM PC console speaker.
 OSS:    Open Sound System /dev/dsp device.  Also works with the newer 
         ALSA Linux sound system using the legacy OSS device.
 PA:     PulseAudio using the pulse-simple client API.
 ALSA:   ALSA Linux sound system /dev/snd/* device.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously calling `pulseaudio`. Start `pulseaudio` or use `morseALSA`